# Finding $\mathrm{vol}(f^{-1}(y))$

Tags: integration, volume

- Consider a many-to-one function $f:X\to Y$
- $X$ is a high-dimensional vector space and $Y$ a low-dimensional vector space
- The analytical form of $f$ is known
- You are probably free to make any 'nice' assumptions about $f$ (e.g. infinitely-differentiable), and the spaces (e.g. Hilbert).
- Let $\mathrm{vol}(f^{-1}(y))$ denote the volume of the subset of $X$ that maps to $y\in Y$.

**Question:**
Are there general methods for computing $\mathrm{vol}(f^{-1}(y))$ (either exactly or to within some arbitrary precision)? Is there an area of mathematics concerned with such calculations?

Comment: There is the co-area formula.